# "Require Installation Of Untrusted Packages" while upgrading with the update manager

Tags: update-manager

[image: screenshot]

It didn't fixed the error. So, how do I fix my GUI update?

For every software I have to install it from command line because I got same error when install software from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: On Software Sources, Ubuntu software tab just change the "download from" parameter to "Server for España". That worked for me.

Comment: the answer is over [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) Its worked quite well for me.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

1. Write in a terminal: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` or edit Update Manager settings (try this first if you have already configured Update Manager).

   [image: CLI]
2. Launch Update Manager and try again.

   [image: GUI]

Running update through a terminal gives option whether to allow or disallow untrusted packages.

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  playonlinux
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

If you trust the package source, type `y`.

Answer (score 44):

This happens due to the missing of some GPG keys. To fix this , Open a terminal and run the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You will get an error saying that some public key is not available. Note the key string ( after the NO_PUBKEY; eg:D6B6DB186A68F637 )

```
 gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv XXXXX
```

Replace the XXXXX with the key string

eg :  `gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv D6B6DB186A68F637`

```
gpg --export --armor  XXXXX | sudo apt-key add -
```

eg: `gpg --export --armor D6B6DB186A68F637 | sudo apt-key add -`

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now try updating your system again.

Here is a similar post: ["Requires to install untrusted updates" Error in Update Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12600/error-in-update-manager/12605#12605)

Hope this helps.

Comment: tried this and I got the message that something has been created, but the update still didn't function. But evgeny's option worked, so no need to troubleshoot what went wrong with your proposal.

Comment: sorry rumtsho. I forgot to add 'gpg --export ' command in my answer. I have updated my answer. Just try it. and check whether the update working or not.

Comment: hmm, I get `gpg: keyserver timed out`; any suggestions?

Comment: Can also use `sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com XXXXXXXXX` from http://askubuntu.com/questions/71188/how-to-bypass-remove-disable-the-untrusted-package-authentication

Answer (score 12):

You can install it via the command line: `sudo apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated exiv2`.

To permanently "trust" the repo, execute this: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pmjdebruijn/darktable-release && sudo apt-get update`. I believe that is the PPA you are using.

Comment: Thank you, the "permanently trust the repo" is what I wanted to achieve and it worked. I just wonder why writing the address in the sources.list doesn't make it trusted, but apt-add-repository does.

Comment: All packages are signed with a cryptographic key, "trusting" the repo involves getting the public key for that repository. You can read about public-key cryptography on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4):

In answer to your question, you **cannot** "fix" the GUI update (i.e. Update Manager), because it is apparent that that application does not currently have the capability of installing untrusted packages. If you want to install untrusted packages, you must do it at the command line.

There are, however, two ways you can stop Update Manager from reporting this error: either remove the untrusted software from your system OR **trust** the repository in question, as outlined in the answer to the other question ( [Updates don't install because of "untrusted packages"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15655/updates-dont-install-because-of-untrusted-packages) ).

The first step is to find out which repository is causing the problem. You can find this out by typing `apt-cache policy ambiance-colors` at the command line.

However, a quick google reveals that `ambiance-colors` and `radiance-colors` are from `ppa:ravefinity-project`. So you should be able to fix your problem by typing

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ambiance-colors radiance-colors
```

taken from http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/ambiance-and-radiance-colors-theme-pack.html

Answer (score 1):

why its saying like that means , the packages you're trying to install are third party software.so if you want to  install them , enable the Canonical Check box at other software Tab  in the settings of update manager and then try again installing .

hope that helps .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me, this command worked:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

The advantage of this compared to the other solutions is its simplicity. You can continue to use the GUI and no need to find out which repository is broken. I found the solution [here](http://ubuntusolved.blogspot.hu/2011/03/requires-installation-of-untrusted.html) in a comment. I don't know Ubuntu enough to explain, but I suppose it gets the keys necessary for all the repos to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear: you "fix your GUI update" by fixing the error. The other [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15655/updates-dont-install-because-of-untrusted-packages) will show you what to do.

You can deselect whatever of your updates is relying on an untrusted source, or you can go ahead and use the command line to trust that particular source permanently. Once you've done one of these, the message won't pop up. If you do the latter, then the message won't ever appear again for that specific source.