# Requires installation of untrusted packages?

Tags: package-management

I tried installing VLC Player yesterday, and I got the `Requires installation of untrusted packages` error.  I searched for hours for a solution to this problem, and finally came upon a suggestion that said to change servers for downloading updates from.  I did this, and it gave me a 404 error when I clicked on "Check" in the Update Manager.  I tried switching my server back to the main one (and after that, several other ones), but I am now still getting a 404 error:
[image]

And the other error I get when downloading or updating:
[image]

Edit:
Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
```

Comment: paste output  `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and then `gpg --list-keys`
paste in paste Ubuntu

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Based on the errors you pasted in the comments section of my previous answer, I have another possible solution:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

This will rebuild the cache.
**Courtesy:**[http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983220#8](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1983220)

Comment: DONT DO THIS: now I just have English and I lost all my other languages packages

Comment: worked for me ~

Answer (score 34):

[This link may help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117015/update-error-require-installation-of-untrusted-packages). It addresses a very similar problem.

Basically, you open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. That did it for me.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer didn't help me in my case (Ubuntu 13.10) but I was able to get around the problem updating through the command line instead of through Software Updater (in case anyone else runs into this problem).

```
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

presented me with the particular package that was coming from an untrusted source (Google's Music Manager) and asked if I wanted to accept it and upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same error while trying to update System Indicator.

In my case it was because of missing GPG keys. There is an answer here that will instruct you to install a PPA manager and it can attempt to import all the missing keys. I did this and it didn't give me any confirmation the missing keys were imported but I ran the update afterwards and it installed fine.

It is a horrible (non-useful) error message I must say in this case.

https://askubuntu.com/a/386003/11929

Comment: This was the issue for me too, then I had to follow the fix of [Jorge M. Treviño](http://askubuntu.com/a/185343/149752) before I could install successfully

Comment: I had issue with apt-fast somehow it could not clean it - so this did not work for me