# Can't install linux headers

Tags: installation, package-management

I keep getting an error:

```
E:The package linux-headers-3.5.0-31-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I have searched everywhere for this error and how to fix it but since this came up there has been no reference to this anywhere.

Any help please or it will be a complete re-install to get rid of the problem.

---

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/main/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)]/ precise main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

Comment: I think your sources are okay. Really strange. Does an error occur if you type sudo apt-get update ? Have you an idea of something you installed or changed which maybe is causing this? What does apt-cache show linux-headers-generic give you?

Comment: I just think I will wipe the install because it is now becoming a pain having to cancel error report 2 or 3 times an hour and no one appears to know what the issue is.  I have another 3 Lenovos all X61s, this one is an X1.  However, two of the others now have the same error.

Comment: I am about to trash my 12.04 LTS now because no one has come up with the answer....  Note I have 3 computers doing this now so it is obviously not an isolated incident.....

Comment: perhaps related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages ?

Answer (score 1):

Try typing

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

into Terminal and press enter, then input your Password (it won't show on the screen, this is normal) and press enter. This will always install the header you need when your kernel gets an update. This is supposed to be installed by default as far as I know.

Comment: main@ThinkPad-X1:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
[sudo] password for main: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-3.5.0-31-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
main@ThinkPad-X1:~$ ^C
main@ThinkPad-X1:~$

Comment: It looks like someone deleted the archive on the web so there is no source for the system to go and get and re-install but won't remove either.

Comment: It looks like Ubuntu is now dead in the water now.  If this problem is not fixable then it is back to Windoze.....

Comment: Nah. Even if we would not find any solution to this, you could just reinstall ubuntu. No reason for Windows. Please tell us, which ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I am running Ubutu 12.10.  I have been using Windoze 7 for the past weeks because have had no time to mess about with this.

Comment: Please try this and copy the result into your Question at the top:
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list