# My system update requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: xubuntu

I'm trying to install the latest updates from my software manager and it wants me to install untrusted packages? Should I install the packages, if so, how? It just says it requires the untrusted packages and when I click OK it goes back to the Software Updater.

Comment: You didn't give us much information. Do you have [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/184117/62483) problem?

Comment: No. I saw that thread and that isn't the same issue as mine. Sorry I didn't mention it before, but it's regular system updates. I'm not trying to install VLC or anything like that.

Comment: But did you get the same window?

Comment: It's similar, but no. I've also run through the steps mentioned in that thread and I'm still having the issue. That's why I made this post in the first place.

Comment: Could you add a screenshoot?

Comment: @Lucio it's not necessary anymore and I can't get to it anyway because I fixed it, I guess. I did `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update` again. I noticed there were 5 updates instead of 3 as there were when I asked this question, but I'm not sure if that is relevant. It ran through just fine and I no longer have an update icon in my tray, so everything seems to be fine. I'm not sure how I fixed it as I said I had already ran those two commands before when I read through the other thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10095/discussion-between-spectro-and-lucio)

Answer (score 2):

Try running `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: This is a dupe of this: http://askubuntu.com/a/185343/62483