# Updates requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: updates

I tried updating using update manager and I got error saying requires installation of untrusted package.

I tried typing get update and get upgrade command in terminal but no avail.

but following shows the result after "get update" in terminal.

```
W: GPG error: http:// archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http:// archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http:// dell.archive.canonical.com precise-dell Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG F9FDA6BED73CDC22 Canonical Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@canonical.com>
```

Here is screen shot for your reference

[image]

I am a very new user to ubuntu. Please help and explain as if you are explaining a child.

Comment: @user68186 I have edited and uploaded pic for your reference

Comment: Try these commands `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 40976EAF437D05B5`,`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com F9FDA6BED73CDC22`

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages (possible duplicate?)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I tried those commands and i am still having the same problem

Comment: after adding that keys, did you run `sudo apt-get update` command?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes i did. I tried this later and it worked 
$ sudo -i
# apt-get clean
# cd /var/lib/apt
# mv lists lists.old
# mkdir -p lists/partial
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update