# Not able to install software on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: apt, software-center, package-management, pdf

I am newbie with Ubuntu.I am trying to download Okular pdf reader from Software Center but I am getting some error.
At first it was asking for installation of packages from not authenticated source,when I click on **Use this source** it goes and do something like

**upadating cache** [image]

Then after some time it shows me this error:
[image]

I read this question ["Requires installation of untrusted packages?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages)and tried to rebuild cache as given in first answer using :

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

and got this output:

```
yogeshwardancharan@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get clean
[sudo] password for yogeshwardancharan: 
yogeshwardancharan@ubuntu:~$ cd /var/lib/apt
yogeshwardancharan@ubuntu:/var/lib/apt$ sudo mv lists lists.old
yogeshwardancharan@ubuntu:/var/lib/apt$ sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
yogeshwardancharan@ubuntu:/var/lib/apt$ sudo apt-get clean
yogeshwardancharan@ubuntu:/var/lib/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]                          
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg                    
Get:5 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,347 B]                            
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                           
Get:6 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1,227 B]                 
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg [316 B]                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release                        
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg          
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release [11.9 kB]             
Get:9 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [710 B]                   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg                 
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release [11.9 kB]                      
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed Release.gpg                  
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources [4,251 B]                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                               
Get:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages [14.3 kB]           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release                       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed Release             
Get:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources [16.7 kB]        
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages [39.4 kB]           
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en                       
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-proposed/universe Translation-en
Fetched 104 kB in 1min 56s (892 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-proposed/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-proposed/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-proposed/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-proposed/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then I tried to re-install Okular but again getting same errors. I have tried changing software source to **Main Server**  and also enabled authentication for third party software sources but still no progress.

Comment: I was not able to download vim-gtk for the same reason as I want to have xterm_clipboard which is possible in vim-gnome.

Comment: please look the answer, http://askubuntu.com/questions/469185/failed-to-fetch-nmap-from-us-archive-ubuntu-com-on-server-14-04-lts/469195#469195

Comment: @xiaodongjie:doing it,let's see whether it gives any result

Comment: It's saying no suitable download server was found.

Comment: The answers are right. 12.10 is not LTS(Long Term Service). 12.04 and 14.04 is LTS version now. I suggest you upgrade or downgrade to  them.

Comment: finally upgrading!

Comment: Here you find an answer: [Archive repository for Ubuntu 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/502413/archive-repository-for-ubuntu-12-10/502420#502420)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.10 is not [supported any more](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/05/01/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-reaches-end-of-life-on-may-16-2014/) since May 2014. You either need to update to a more recent version of Ubuntu (i.e. 14.04), or find an alternative repository. The alternative repository for 12.10 is released [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/) (thanks @rubo77 for finding it). More information on upgrading can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release).

Comment: so,does that means I can't download any software from now on without updating?

Comment: If you find an archived repository for 12.10, you might switch to that. I looked, and could not find one. It should appear here eventually: old-releases.ubuntu.com

Comment: Although the old releae for quantal is not listed, it is there: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/ see [here for how to update your `sources.list`](http://askubuntu.com/a/502425/34298)

Answer (score 0):

As 12.10 is EOL, the repos for it have moved. Upgrade to a newer version of ubuntu (or downgrade to 12.04, though that is really not recommended) to access the normal repos. If you absolutely need to use that version of ubuntu, consider adding the archive repos, google for instructions on how to do that. In the end my answer is upgrade to 14.04, it's more stable and has support