# Archive repository for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: apt

Ubuntu 12.10 is not [supported any more](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/05/01/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-reaches-end-of-life-on-may-16-2014/) since May 2014.

Why is there no archived version at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: Related to(can be a duplicate): http://askubuntu.com/q/483906/184942

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/

Comment: it's here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/ Somebody has forgotten to add it to the list but the files have been moved

Comment: That site http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/  still seems a bit mixed up and also the link to the current releases at http://releases.ubuntu.com/ lists releases that the lifetime has ended already. Who is managing that lists? and who is moving releases to old.releases?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although the Files for quantal are not listed, the files have actually been moved and can be found here:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal

edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change 'archive.ubuntu.com' to 'old-releases.ubuntu.com'

You can do this with sed

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then update with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Attention**: you should only use the old-release archive if you have no possibility to upgrade to a newer version, because you **won't get any security updates** using these old archives

Comment: Do you by any chance now if the security upgrades for quantal can be found somewhere? Or are they incorporated into `old-releases.ubuntu.com`?