# apt-get broken in 12.10 fresh install

Tags: apt

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10, and can't install build-essential or git.

I had internet on and checked both options, to install 3rd party and to download updates while installing.

`sudo apt-get update` says:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

carmen@SERENITY:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential git subversion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
E: Unable to locate package git
E: Unable to locate package subversion
```

How am I supposed to use Ubuntu now?

Comment: 12.10 went end of life a while ago, the repos are not online any more, you need to upgrade to a supported release http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it is the only version officially supported by Steam for their games

Comment: No it is not, I have 16.04 steam is perfect, it will work on any version. I don't know where you heard that but it is wrong.

Comment: Linux distributions supported by Steam.
https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1504-QHXN-8366

Comment: It's important because I am trying to port my game to Ubuntu, and Steam won't offer any support if you're not on their official version. So I guess I have to install 12.04; I just mistakenly thought 12.10 would be better since it is the newer of the two supported options.

Comment: You can't install them because apt-get update is not working ..  Try to use another mirror , [click me](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104695/how-do-i-change-mirrors-in-ubuntu-server-from-regional-to-main)

Comment: That information is years out of date but it also says 12.04, that is LTS 2 years left on its support, use that if you worrie but it works on any supported version, just run `sudo apt-get install steam` and it will install.

Comment: @AhmedJerbi No it is because 12.10 is end of life, no more support, no more repos.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Where does Steam say that they won't offer support unless you're on 12.04/12.10?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju It does say that here https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1504-QHXN-8366 and it was true when steam first came out but I just think they never bothered to update it.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Most likely they forgot to update that page, I'm sure it works on 16.04, as MarkKirby confirmed.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn, 12.10 : You can change the links in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to point to "old-releases" → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNU2YxUExIWERjV2s/view?usp=sharing -

Comment: @KnudLarsen It can be done sure, but it should be discouraged as there are no security updates or anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 12.10 is no longer supported, which means that the repositories are no longer maintained.

There's two options:

- Upgrade to, or install, a newer version of Ubuntu (eg. 16.04). Steam runs perfectly fine on 16.04.
- [Use the Archive repository for 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/502413/archive-repository-for-ubuntu-12-10). Note that this is no longer supported, meaning that you will no longer get security and other updates.