# software install issue with package manager

Tags: 13.04

My OS is Ubuntu 13.04

Recently something had happened with Pacakage Manager and its giving issues when i try install some software.

If i try to install from Ubuntu Software Center, it says

> Requires installation of untrusted packages
>
> This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.

And if try to install from console it says:

```
apt-get install ipython
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares-dev libev-dev libev4 libjs-node-uuid libssl-dev libssl-doc libv8-3.8.9.20 libv8-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-decorator python-simplegeneric
Suggested packages:
  ipython-doc ipython-notebook ipython-qtconsole python-matplotlib python-numpy python-zmq
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ipython python-decorator python-simplegeneric
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 698 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,064 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  python-decorator python-simplegeneric ipython
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main python-decorator all 3.3.3-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe python-simplegeneric all 0.8.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe ipython all 0.13.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-decorator/python-decorator_3.3.3-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/simplegeneric/python-simplegeneric_0.8.1-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/ipython/ipython_0.13.2-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I followed the accepted answer at [Requires installation of untrusted packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages) and now situation is worse then earlier :(

Now if try to install something from console it says:

```
apt-get install ipython
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ipython
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: 13.04 (Raring) is no more supported. So it is no more present on the mirror you are using (404 error). You can check by opening the URL in a web browser, you will see that there is no more *raring* directory on this mirror. So you should upgrade to a supported version like 14.04 LTS.

Comment: yeah, i know that but i thouht that `no more supported` means no updates will be pushed to 13.04, i should never get 404, it means they have delete the repos? Please correct me?

Answer (score 0):

have you done what the message suggested?

> maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing

Comment: yeah. no effect.