# Can't install updates

Tags: updates, update-manager

I'm pretty new to ubuntu, I started using it about a month ago, and ever since I installed it I haven't been able to install updates. When I go to System Settings>details>install updates, it shows me a long list of updates. When I click install updates I get a pop up window that says "Requires installation of untrusted packages - This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources."

I can click Settings or OK. If I click okay it closes without updating anything, and if I click Setting it brings me to the update settings window but I don't really know what to do there.

I know how to work with the terminal if that's the case, but I'd like to know how to make this Software Updater work the way it's supposed to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requires installation of untrusted packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages)

Answer (score 1):

- first install Y-PPA manager:
  for this you have to download deb package, you cant install through PPA, since you cant update software list.

  [click on this link to download deb](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/getdeb-apps-i386/y-ppa-manager_0.0.9.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb.html)
- then open it and click on Advanced Option.

[image: Advanced Option in Y-PPA manager]

- then click on the second option( try to import all missing GPG keys) shown in image below:

[image: gpgkeys-import in Y-PPA manager]

- wait for some time. Then click on third option (try to fix all GPG BADSIG errors)
  You need to wait for some time untill its shows you notification that its done !
- in case you have upgraded your Ubuntu recently, you have to click on "Re-enable working PPAs after Ubuntu upgrade"
- then run `sudo apt-get update` After this you can go back to thing you were trying to do.