# Error message W: GPG error

Tags: upgrade, updates

After updating my system as usual from the terminal it goes on fetching updates but at last it shows the following messages. What does it mean and how do I fix the red icon. Actually to fix the red icon I updated but it isn't fixed. 
The message:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty 
Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1DB8ADC1CFCA9579
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And also I could not update recommended **Updates**, every time I hit **Install** off course after authentication a message pops up. How do I fix this annoying message. I want to run my system with anomaly(s). Who wouldn't? 
[image: Required installtion of untrusted packages]

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean` followed by `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Thanks man. The red Icon is gone but what about the error message about Problem no:1:- The message:-”http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1DB8ADC1CFCA9579 W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en Hash Sum mismatch E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.”"> I had two set of problems. Help is needed.

Comment: for problem no. 1 try this:http://askubuntu.com/a/553030/294611

Comment: Otherwise `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Type the following commands in a Terminal -

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

`sudo apt-get update`

This will remove your lists and fetch a new copy of it.

Otherwise, as [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553014/cant-install-updates/553030#553030) by @edwardtorvalds, try to import all the missing gpg keys.