# What is GPG error?

Tags: updates, gnupg

When my update is complete I am getting an `GPG` error but I don't know what is `GPG`.Can someone explain me what is this error and why it has occurred?
I know how to fix it but I want to know what is this error ?

the error is:

```
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A902DDA375E52366
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the error message?

Comment: Could just be a warning that someone's key isn't fully "trusted", if it's not signed by you or someone else you "trust", but would have to see the erorr to know for sure

Comment: following [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/553030/294611) procedure may help you to get ride of that question. if thats what you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Comment: No this question is different

Comment: @SurayansTiwari: How is it different? It's the same error, and the same solution.

Comment: Hey dude I am not asking the technique to fix it , I am asking that tell me more about this error ,What is this error,from where it came from .

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you have added a non-ubuntu repository to your apt sources, but you have not imported the public key that matches the signing key that was used to sign the packages in that repository.

You can run the following command in order to import the missing key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A902DDA375E52366
```

Comment: now getting this error `Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.MHiCXTRgnn --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nilarimogard-webupd8.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-sublime-text-3.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A902DDA375E52366
gpg: requesting key 75E52366 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error`

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes I am ,is this because of proxy?

Comment: Looks like something is blocking your access to keyserver.ubuntu.com, so firewall or proxy are likely to blame.