# Issue to download Libreoffice Base bibliography tool

Tags: package-management, libreoffice, downloads, database

Good evening!

I want to create a bibliography for a thesis but I can't download the related Libreoffice tool because the necessary package is untrusted for my computer. Each time I try I get the following error message:

```
libreoffice-base libreoffice-base-drivers libreoffice-sdbc-firebird libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb
```

Here is a pic of the situation:

[image]

Can you help me download it or find an alternative solution?

Comment: @edwinksl It is on this page that I found and created my solution 2 minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer adapting thanks to [saji89's one on how to install untrusted package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages)

sudo apt-get clean

Based on the errors you pasted in the comments section of my previous answer, I have another possible solution:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

I don't know why it worked but I was then able to install the tool!