# Update manager will not update due to authentication error

Tags: 12.04, updates, authentication

I press 'Install Updates' and then it will say

> Requires installation of untrusted packages
>
> The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.

then it will ask me to close. This happens for *every* update. It seems the update manager is self-defeating.

The details section is a mess. It just seems to list all the updates that won't work, ie all:

> 0ad 0ad-data 0ad-data-common activity-log-manager-common activity-log-manager-control-center apparmor appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 apport apport-gtk apport-symptoms apt apt-transport-https apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data bamfdaemon base-files bind9-host brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common busybox-initramfs busybox-static colord compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default coreutils cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-ppdc dnsutils firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer gdb gimp gimp-data gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-power-manager gnome-settings-daemon gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter icedtea-7-jre-jamvm im-switch indicator-messages indicator-status-provider-mc5 jockey-common jockey-gtk landscape-client-ui-install libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libavcodec53 libavdevice53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libbamf0 libbamf3-0 libbind9-80 libbrasero-media3-1 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libcolord1 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libdecoration0 libdns81 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfreerdp1 libgail-3-0 libgimp2.0 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglu1-mesa libgnome-control-center1 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgudev-1.0-0 libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libindicator-messages-status-provider1 libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82 libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libldap-2.4-2 liblwres80 libnautilus-extension1a liboverlay-scrollbar-0.2-0 liboverlay-scrollbar3-0.2-0 libparted0debian1 libperl5.14 libpostproc52 libproxy1 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpython3.2 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libssh-4 libswscale2 libtiff4 libudev0 libunity-core-5.0-5 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libxatracker1 libxcb-composite0 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-xv0 libxcb1 libxml2 light-themes linux-generic-pae linux-headers-3.2.0-35 linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic-pae linux-headers-generic-pae linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae linux-libc-dev lsb-base lsb-release make multiarch-support nautilus nautilus-data openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib overlay-scrollbar parted perl perl-base perl-modules python-apport python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.pkcompat python-keyring python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-problem-report python-ubuntu-sso-client python3.2 python3.2-minimal qdbus seahorse thunderbird thunderbird-globalmenu thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-sso-client-qt udev unity unity-common unity-greeter unity-lens-applications unity-services update-notifier update-notifier-common xserver-xorg-input-wacom xul-ext-ubufox

Mind you, it does this even for the Ubuntu updates. I've checked the authentication in the settings and nothing seems to be the problem.

Comment: Did you check this question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center

If you still get some errors, don't forget to mention them.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` from the command line and report back the error message.

Comment: Perhaps related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Require Installation Of Untrusted Packages" while upgrading with the update manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117015/require-installation-of-untrusted-packages-while-upgrading-with-the-update-man)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. I checked the settings and made sure that the update server was the one I wanted. Sometimes, I've found that changing the server also helps. After making sure the settings are correct, I click "check." This makes the computer verify that it is connected with the server and has the right updates for my machine. The final keystroke is to click "install updates." The update started for me, as usual. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the updater is working off an outdated cache. It appears to be checking for updates every time you open it, but it doesn't actually perform an apt-get update unless you click the "Check" button.

This is how I realized that I didn't have an internet connection, which was the original cause of the problem.