# audio and video players are not working

Tags: sound, video

04.2.
i want to install vlc and other media players. i tried through ubuntu soft center but it shows error message like
"Requires installation of untrusted packages. The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.". 
Even i tried movie player but it shows the same for requirements updates when updating. please help me. please suggest a way to work in it.

Comment: yes accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start with these suggestions:
["Require Installation Of Untrusted Packages" while upgrading with the update manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117015/update-error-require-installation-of-untrusted-packages)
Basically, open the terminal and type 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Then open the software center.  Click edit menu > software sources
Try checking more of the boxes.
Also try working through some of the other suggestions on that page.