# “Require Installation Of Untrusted Packages” while upgrading with the update manager

Tags: apt, updates

I realise there are other answers out there, specifically this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117015/require-installation-of-untrusted-packages-while-upgrading-with-the-update-man) but my question is slightly different in that most of the missing keys are from ubuntu-dot-com, Does this suggest the key store may be corrupt?

Error from sudo apt-get update:

```
 W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

 With similar errors for;

 W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release:
 W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: 
 W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntucom trusty-security InRelease:
 W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease:
 W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease:
 W: GPG error: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release:
```

Is there a quick way to reload these keys or does each one need to be done individually?

Answer (score 0):

OK seems I solved it reasonably easily :)

ran

```
sudo apt-key update
```

And most of the ubuntu.com errors went so I just then had to do a couple of others manually.

HTH