# Update Manager error 12.04

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. When attempting to run my Update Manager, it doesn't allow any of the updates to be loaded. Under "details" all it says is "patch". It won't even load anything when the Partial Upgrade option comes up. I thought that this ["Requires to install untrusted updates" Error in Update Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12600/error-in-update-manager) would help me, but when I followed the instruction and looked for the "PUBKEY" in Terminal, there was none, it said "BADSIG" and "failed to fetch 11.10" instead and my Update Manager still doesn't update anything. I'm still new to the finer points of Ubuntu and could really use some advice. Did I do something wrong? Or I need to do a fresh install?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try removing all .list files and downloading from the repo again.

Type 
           `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`
into terminal followed by:
           `sudo apt-get update`