# Requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: updates

I have been trying to update Ubuntu, but these three updates below are not letting me update anything else. I have tried unselecting them from the update list but Ubuntu still won’t update the rest.

I really don’t know what to do here; a friend of mine put ubuntu onto my computer, which I only really use for internet and word processing. Hopefully I am giving you enough information; thanks for any advice or tips you might have.

```
direct frame buffer graphics - shared libraries  
libdirectfb-1.2-9 

touch screen library  
libts-0.0-0

tsconf  
touch screen library common files
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Requires to install untrusted updates" Error in Update Manager](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12600/requires-to-install-untrusted-updates-error-in-update-manager)

Comment: @zwets how you know that? He's trying to upgrade, not to install.

Comment: @braiam that is title of the question (but not clarified in the question); otherwise, it is a very likely duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/117015/update-error-require-installation-of-untrusted-packages?rq=1

Comment: @zwets title doesn't make questions, read the body too. "I have been trying to **update** Ubuntu" there are two possibilities, either apt-get or Software Center, and OP doesn't explain which of them.

Answer (score 3):

Short version:

- You need to update your "index of the repositories".

  - If you are using the GUI (graphical user interface; in this case, the "Update
    Manager" window), then click the "Check" button first.  When it finishes, you
    should then be able to click "Install Updates" and will experience no problems.
  - If you are using the command line, then execute command 1 before your usual
    command 2:

    1. `sudo apt-get update`
    2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Long version:

The long version requires an understanding of the repository methodology.  In short, as compared to the historical method on Windows or Mac, where you go to various websites, download the piece of software you want, and install it, most Linux distributions (Ubuntu included) rely on a repository.  The repository is a community resource administered by maintainers that is basically a huge source of available software for your machine.  The upside is that installing software from the repository ensures that you do not install rogue software (i.e., malware), and that *all* software on your machine stays automatically up-to-date.

Whenever the community repositories update a package, they also update meta information about the package (the version number, basically).  The meta information includes a digital signature that ensures that when you download the update, that you downloaded the correct update, and that it wasn't corrupted in transit.  The message you are receiving is basically saying that the package updates you would be downloading do not match what your copy of the repository indexes suggest they should be.  Nine times out of ten, this means that you need to grab an updated copy of the indexes.  Hence, `sudo apt-get update` is your friend.

For more information on "this repository thing," check out the [Ubuntu wiki entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).