# Why am I unable to update from Software Updater?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I am unable to update through software updater. After clicking install now, it shows "requires installation from untrusted package".

Then there is two options: Settings and OK. 
I click OK but the software updater window closes and stops.

Comment: This is irritating i cant post screenshots

Comment: you can't able to post a image.please post the image link.

Comment: @user204983 upload it into imgur.com and paste the link into your question editing it. You can try to solve the problem following [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/12605/62483) procedure. Tell us if that doesn't work

Comment: Looks like key error issue. Some repository site's gpg key is missing maybe. run in terminal (sudo apt-get update), post the output(last section/errors).

Answer (score 0):

might be useful to look at your sources file you can get it like this:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

but you might try this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages)